# Spring @Transactional JPA within a JMSConsumer Camel processor

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel, spring-transactions, openjpa

I'am in the process of updating an existing Java SE Camel Application to make use of Spring JPA managed EntityManger using @PersitentContext injection. Currently  it is instanciated in our code using  Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory and it works well. But we'd like to have more flexible and testable application by using injection of this entityManager, use the powerful @Transactional aop capacities and also to switch between local and global XA transactions just by using different @Configuration @Profiles.

My first test was to test xa transactions involving JMS and JPA resources with an Atomikos TransactionManager and it worked.

Now in this application I want to test local transactions using OpenJPA, Camel and JpaTransactionManager i.e without involving XA transaction.

I have unit tests that works pretty well without Camel, the @Transactional weaving does the work of starting transactions with the jpaTransactionManager and everything is fine.

Now when I try to integrate my configuration beans into the camel applications things are not going well.

I have a JMS consumer that triggers a camel processor where the process method is annotated with @Transactional.

I think I have misconfigured something because the JMSConsumer start a transaction even tough I did not set up the JMS component explicitly for being transactional (no transacted() in the route, not transaction manager set to the JMSConfiguration)

Here is a breakpoint showing the JmsConsumer trying registering to the transaction synchronisation stuff:

```
Daemon Thread [Camel (worker) thread #1 - JmsConsumer[<consumerName>]] (Suspended (breakpoint at line 175 in TransactionSynchronizationManager))
    TransactionSynchronizationManager.bindResource(Object, Object) line: 175
    DefaultJmsMessageListenerContainer(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer).doReceiveAndExecute(Object, Session, MessageConsumer, TransactionStatus) line: 313
    DefaultJmsMessageListenerContainer(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer).receiveAndExecute(Object, Session, MessageConsumer) line: 255
    DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener() line: 1168
    DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop() line: 1160
    DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run() line: 1057
    ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) line: 1142
    ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() line: 617   
    Thread.run() line: 745 [local variables unavailable]
```

I don't see any other resource being bound to the TransactionSynchronisationManager.

On the contrary in my unit tests seems are going well and we see in the stack trace the @Transactional playing its role as expected:

```
Thread [main] (Suspended (breakpoint at line 175 in TransactionSynchronizationManager))
    TransactionSynchronizationManager.bindResource(Object, Object) line: 175
    JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(Object, TransactionDefinition) line: 406
    JpaTransactionManager(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager).getTransaction(TransactionDefinition) line: 377
    TransactionInterceptor(TransactionAspectSupport).createTransactionIfNecessary(PlatformTransactionManager, TransactionAttribute, String) line: 461
    TransactionInterceptor(TransactionAspectSupport).invokeWithinTransaction(Method, Class<?>, InvocationCallback) line: 277
    TransactionInterceptor.invoke(MethodInvocation) line: 96    
    CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation(ReflectiveMethodInvocation).proceed() line: 179
    CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Object, Method, Object[], MethodProxy) line: 671
    MyRepo$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5edadd7f.createRun(String) line: not available
    DataSourceConfigTest.testIt2() line: 38 
    ...
```

So clearly something is misconfigured here it seems @Transactional is totally ignored or overridden by some magic auto-configuration of SpringBoot. Does anyone has any hint ?

Here is my CamelConfiguration and My Data/JPA configuration

Camel Config

```
@Configuration
public class CamelConfiguration {
    protected static Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CamelConfiguration.class);


    @Value("${broker.mqURL}")
    String mqURL;

    /**
     * The runId is injected from command Line arguments
     */
    @Value("${runId}")
    long runId;


    @Bean
    CamelContextConfiguration contextConfiguration() {
        return new CamelContextConfiguration() {
            @Override
            public void beforeApplicationStart(CamelContext context) {

                ((SpringCamelContext)context).setName("worker");

                DefaultShutdownStrategy shutdownStrategy = new DefaultShutdownStrategy();
                shutdownStrategy.setTimeUnit(TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                shutdownStrategy.setTimeout(5);
                context.setShutdownStrategy(shutdownStrategy);
            }

            @Override
            public void afterApplicationStart(CamelContext camelContext) {
                try {
                    LOGGER.info("Starting route dataspecProcessing." + runId);
                    camelContext.startAllRoutes();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    LOGGER.error("Error during Camel post start",e);
                }
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope(value = ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_SINGLETON)
    public ActiveMQConnectionFactory jmsConnectionFactory() {
        ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
        connectionFactory.setBrokerURL(mqURL);
        connectionFactory.setTrustAllPackages(true);
        return connectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope(value = ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_SINGLETON)
    public JmsConfiguration myJmsConfiguration(ActiveMQConnectionFactory jmsConnectionFactory,JpaTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager) {
        JmsConfiguration jmsConfiguration = new JmsConfiguration();
//      jmsConfiguration.setTransacted(true);
//      jmsConfiguration.setLazyCreateTransactionManager(false);
//      jmsConfiguration.setTransactionManager(jpaTransactionManager);
        jmsConfiguration.setConnectionFactory(jmsConnectionFactory);
        jmsConfiguration.setCacheLevelName("CACHE_CONSUMER");
        return jmsConfiguration;
    }
```

Jpa Config

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement(mode=AdviceMode.ASPECTJ)
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)
public class DataSourceConfig {

    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
        transactionManager.setDataSource(dataSource());
        transactionManager.setJpaDialect(new OpenJpaDialect());
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setPersistenceXmlLocation("META-INF/persistence.xml");
        em.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());
        em.setDataSource(dataSource());
        em.setValidationMode(ValidationMode.NONE);
        JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new OpenJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        em.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());

        return em;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        PGSimpleDataSource pgDataSource = new PGSimpleDataSource();
        pgDataSource.setUrl(...);
        pgDataSource.setUser(...);
        pgDataSource.setPassword(...);
        return pgDataSource;
    }
```

And the code that should be transactional

```
@Component
@EnableTransactionManagement(mode=AdviceMode.ASPECTJ)
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)
public class MyCamelProcessor implements Processor {
...
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW,transactionManager="jpaTransactionManager")
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        ... calls to entitymanager here ...
```

The route calling the processor

```
@Component
public class DataSpecProcessingRoute extends SpringRouteBuilder {
....
public void configure() throws Exception {
...
from("jms:queue:thequeue"?concurrentConsumers=" + numConsumerThreads)
            .autoStartup(false)
        .shutdownRunningTask(ShutdownRunningTask.CompleteCurrentTaskOnly)
                .routeId("dataspecProcessing." + runId)
                .process(initialisationProcessor)
                .process(processorWithTransactionnalNeeded)
.to("jms:queue:anotherqueue") ;
```

**EDIT**

It works with programmatic transactions, not with @Transactional annotation.

Comment: Can you show the code where you configure the route?

Comment: I just added the code of the route (a bit stripped). One point to notice is that each JMS consumer is ran in its own thread and that our processors are run with these thread (They are not asynchronous).

Comment: You should read http://camel.apache.org/how-do-i-make-my-jms-endpoint-transactional.html

Comment: I also notice that for still unknown reason  each call to the store wrapping the entitymanager creates an entitymanager. I see this entry in the logs 
"Creating new EntityManager for shared EntityManager invocation"
I'd like to only have one per transaction.

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I don't want to use JMS transactions now... This I know how to proceed. The problem is with spring JPA transactions.

Comment: Camel has its own definition of transactionality and it relies more on convention over configuration to accomplish it.  It can be tough to follow the documentation on it, but [it is well worth the read](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/camel-core/src/main/docs/eips/transactional-client.adoc).  Making your processor exclusively transactional isn't the approach you *want* since you could put any *other* processor in there and the entire route would not be considered transactional.

Comment: @Makoto Sorry I'am not sure to understand your point. As I said I don't want a JMS transactional endPoint so why do you give a link to the JMS transaction doc. I'am afrais that my question is not well explained :(
 I know how to achieve JMS transactions and actually I use it in production. In my case I want a simple camel processor performing a simple Jpa/sql transaction.  Maybe do you mean that the Transactional Spring annotation is overridden in a sense by Camel configuration? If you know more about it I would be super grateful.

Comment: That `transacted()` operation doesn't just handle JMS transactions.  It can also explicitly handle database transactions.

Comment: But for that you need XA transactions which I also successfully tested :)
Also I don't use transacted() in my route, don't want to. I just wanted to have simple spring jpa transaction in a processor. So I could make it using programmatic transactions (see my EDIT) but not with the annotation...

Comment: You don't need XA transactions for that at all.  I've used this approach to ensure that my database rolls back when an error happens during processing in that route and it works very, very well.  I'm not sure where you're getting this level of distrust for Camel's transactional routes, but it's more effort to fight against them than to leverage them.

Comment: @Makoto Actually I see what you mean: I tested earlier that I can use the jpaTransactionManager within a transacted route. For that you inject the jpaTransactionManager in the jmsConfiguration and it works. Note that in this case the JMS message itselft won't be consumed in a transaction.. But this is not what I wanted to achieve. Btw I don't distrust camel I'am just trying to make things works :) Thanks anyway for your time